# PhpStorm won't connect to remote MySQL via SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, phpstorm, ssh-tunnel, datagrip

Today PhpStorm won't connect to MySQL on the remote server via SSH tunnel.

SSH configuration test runs successfully (authentication to SSH via key pair)

Test of MySQL connection fails with the below error:

> Failed
>
> DBMS: MySQL (ver. 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)  Case sensitivity: plain=exact, delimited=exact Driver: MySQL Connector/J (ver. mysql-connector-java-8.0.25 (Revision: 08be9e9b4cba6aa115f9b27b215887af40b159e0), JDBC4.2)
>
> SSH tunnel creation failed: Connection refused.

General settings (weren't changed):

- Driver: MySQL
- Authentication: User and Password
- User, database, password are correct.

The only thing that was changed today from my side is reset of MySQL root password at the server (my this [instruction](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-20-04)). But I'm trying to connect not from root but from a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

Very soon I've found solution by my self.

The problem is that during changing of MySQL root password by [manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password-on-ubuntu-20-04) the bellow command didn't work as expected.

```
sudo systemctl revert mysql
```

After this command below file and directory shall be removed

```
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf.
/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d.
```

After I checked, this file and directory were still in the place, so I've removed it manually and ran other commands:

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/override.conf.
sudo rm -r /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d.

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

After this trick PHPStorm MySQL connection via ssh tunnel returned.